# Native Crashes on few Android version 23 Phones

Tags: android, native

For the last 2 months, we have started seeing crashes on Samsung Android j7elte Android Version 23. Any starting point on how to debug this? Any help would be appreciated.

---

stackTrace :

```
  #00  pc 0000000000207552  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb1EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+505)
  #01  pc 000000000020b787  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb1EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+790)
  #02  pc 00000000000afa7d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb1ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+25796)
  #03  pc 00000000001ec79d  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+336)
  #04  pc 00000000002076c1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb1EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+872)
  #05  pc 0000000000209e93  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE1ELb0ELb1EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+538)
  #06  pc 00000000000afb1d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb1ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+25956)
  #07  pc 00000000001ec79d  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+336)
  #08  pc 0000000000206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
  #09  pc 00000000000c01f7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+25142)
  #10  pc 00000000001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
  #11  pc 0000000000206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
  #12  pc 000000000020af5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+538)
  #13  pc 00000000000c0695  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+26324)
  #14  pc 00000000001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
  #15  pc 0000000000206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
  #16  pc 00000000000c01f7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+25142)
  #17  pc 00000000001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
  #18  pc 0000000000206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
  #19  pc 00000000000c09fd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+27196)
  #20  pc 00000000001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
  #21  pc 0000000000206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
  #22  pc 00000000000c01f7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+25142)
  #23  pc 00000000001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
  #24  pc 0000000000206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
  #25  pc 000000000020af5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+538)
  #26  pc 00000000000c0695  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+26324)
  #27  pc 00000000001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
  #28  pc 0000000000206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
  #29  pc 00000000000c01f7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+25142)
  #30  pc 00000000001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
  #31  pc 0000000000206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
  #32  pc 000000000020af5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+538)
  #33  pc 00000000000c0695  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+26324)
  #34  pc 00000000001ec479  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+80)
  #35  pc 00000000004015ad  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+548)
  #36  pc 00000000000ea923  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+34)
  #37  pc 000000000336d525  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

Comment: where do these logs come from ? crashlytics or an actual device ?

Comment: if the device is cheap enough, consider trying to buy one to test it, i know this isn't much of an answer but we often end up doing that for specific devices giving issues

Comment: Not getting this device in market and this device has good percentage of active users.

Comment: ahh that's a problem, goodluck then, hope you find an answer :)

Comment: What about virtual device for this phone? Is it not good enough?

Comment: will i able to make virtual device for this phone that will be a replica of this device?